# Android SQLite read blob

Tags: android, sqlite, jpeg, android-sqlite, endianness

I have an sqlite database which is written to from a service running on windows(C++). I am now trying to read from this same sqlite database which contains some blob data. I have some code as follows:

```
String tileQuery = "SELECT * FROM '" + layerName + "' WHERE zoom_level=?";
Cursor tileCursor = database.rawQuery(tileQuery, new String[] {zoom_level});
if( tileCursor.moveToFirst() )
{
    while( !tileCursor.isAfterLast() )
    {
        int tileRow = tileCursor.getInt(tileCursor.getColumnIndex("tile_row"));
        int tileColumn = tileCursor.getInt(tileCursor.getColumnIndex("tile_column"));
        byte[] tileData = tileCursor.getBlob(tileCursor.getColumnIndex("tile_data"));

        //Write tile to file
        String fileName = layerName + "_" + zoom_level + "_" + tileRow + "_" + tileColumn + ".jpeg";

        try {
            /*
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + TILE_STORAGE_PATH + "/" + fileName));
            bos.write(tileData);
            bos.flush();
            bos.close();
            */
            ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(tileData);
            bb.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + TILE_STORAGE_PATH + "/" + fileName);
            byte[] toWrite = new byte[bb.remaining()];
            bb.get(toWrite, 0 , toWrite.length);
            fos.write(toWrite);
            fos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
        }

        tileCursor.moveToNext();
    }
}
```

As shown, I am attempting to write the blobs to disk as jpeg images. No matter what I do, the images appear to be corrupt, as in I cannot view them on any image viewer within android. The same images can be written to file on windows and viewed correctly, which made me think that it was an endianess issue(due to the fact that the blob was written to the database via a service running on windows). I have tried changing the byte order and writing to disk again, but I get the same result. Could anyone suggest what I might be doing wrong/missing. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this work there are a few different steps. Assuming your database connection is working and those are the correct columns you are looking in with your `Cursor`

(1) Convert the blob to a `Bitmap`. You can use the blob you get back, assuming you actually downloaded and stored it to your local database, as the byte[] you will decode.

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(tileData, 0 ,tileData.length);
```

(2) Create a new file in the approprite directory and write to that file. You can do that with something like the code below. The idea is to get the local directory

```
private void storeBitmap(Bitmap myBitmap){
    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/your_directory_name");

    String fname = "your_file_name.jpg";
    File file = new File (myDir, fname);
    if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

If you want to add the images to gallery or you just want a different (and potentially easier) way to add the file, look into using `MediaScanner` which will add the files as though you took the picture with your camers

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have already tried both methods suggested by you, but I get the same result. Using bitmap.compress results in an output file which is of size 0KB. Writing the byte array directly to a file results in a file of the correct size (> 0KB). However, this file appears to be corrupted as I cannot view it in any viewer.

Comment: Hmm. Well if your file size is always 0kb I'm not sure I can help. You may want to make sure you're downloading the correct information. Just to double check - you have permissions declared in your manafest to read/write to external storage?

Comment: Thanks for your input, i figured out that the issue was in fact due to the blob data being corrupted. I shall mark your answer as a solution due to the fact that what you have provided should allow a user to write the images to disk. Thanks for the input